# How to implement marketplace: admin side show complete orders with list of purchased items: A challenge I cannot tackle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, admin

I'm currently stuck on a problem that I do not know how to tackle. I am currently working on a marketplace and a user can successfully, browse items, add items to cart and successfully purchase them items that are in a cart. I'm trying to build an admin side for the sellers to show a list of items that have been purchased but I am struggling as I do not know how to implement.

I have had a few ideas but nothing I think of seems to work.

If anyone can solve this I would be entirely grateful!

**database**

```
  create_table "carts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

create_table "line_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "product_id", null: false
    t.bigint "cart_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "quantity", default: 1
    t.bigint "order_id"
    t.index ["cart_id"], name: "index_line_items_on_cart_id"
    t.index ["order_id"], name: "index_line_items_on_order_id"
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_line_items_on_product_id"
  end

  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "address"
    t.string "email"
    t.integer "pay_type"
    t.boolean "complete", default: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.decimal "price", precision: 8, scale: 2
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_products_on_user_id"
  end
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "username"
    t.string "name"
    t.boolean "admin", default: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "uid"
    t.string "provider"
    t.string "access_code"
    t.string "publishable_key"
    t.string "stripe_id"
    t.boolean "subscribed"
    t.string "card_last4"
    t.string "card_exp_month"
    t.string "card_exp_year"
    t.string "card_type"
    t.text "perk_subscriptions", default: [], array: true
    t.string "s_name"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

**cart_controller**

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :invalid_cart

  def index
    @carts = Cart.all
  end

  def show
  end


  def new
    @cart = Cart.new
  end


  def edit
  end


  def create
    @cart = Cart.new(cart_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart.save
        format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cart }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart.update(cart_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @cart }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @cart.destroy if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
    session["cart_id"] = nil
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to store_index_url, notice: 'Cart was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_cart
      @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
    end

    def cart_params
      params.fetch(:cart, {})
    end

    def invalid_cart
      logger.error "Attempt to access invalid cart #{params[:id]}"
      redirect_to store_index_url, notice: 'Invalid cart'
    end
    
end
```

**lineitem controller**

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]
  before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @line_items = LineItem.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @line_item = LineItem.new
  end


  def edit
  end


  def create
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to(request.env['HTTP_REFERER']) }
        format.js {@current_item = @line_item}
        format.json { render :show, 
          status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.update(line_item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item, notice: 'Line item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @line_item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to line_items_url, notice: 'Line item was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_line_item
      @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    end


    def line_item_params
      params.require(:line_item).permit(:product_id)
    end
end
```

**order controller**

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:new, :create]
  before_action :ensure_cart_isnt_empty, only: :new
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /orders
  # GET /orders.json
  def index
    @orders = Order.all
  end

  # GET /orders/1
  # GET /orders/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /orders/new
  def new
    @order = Order.new
  end

  # GET /orders/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @order.add_line_items_from_cart(@cart)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
        session[:cart_id] = nil
        format.html { redirect_to store_index_url, notice: 'Thank you for your order' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1
  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update(order_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /orders/1
  # DELETE /orders/1.json
  def destroy
    @order.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to orders_url, notice: 'Order was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:name, :address, :email, :pay_type)
    end

    def ensure_cart_isnt_empty
      if @cart.line_items.empty?
        redirect_to store_index_url, notice: 'Your cart is empty'
      end
    end 
    
end
```

**product controller**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /products/new
  def new
    @product = Product.new
    @product.user = current_user
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    @product.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
          if current_user.can_receive_payments?
            UploadProductJob.perform_now(@product)
          end
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /products/1
  # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :price, :category_id)
    end
end
```

**cart model**

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

    def add_product(product)
        current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product.id)
        if current_item
          current_item.quantity += 1
        else 
          current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product.id)
        end
        current_item
      end 
      
      def total_price
        line_items.to_a.sum{ |item| item.total_price }
      end 
      
end
```

**line_item model**

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order, optional: true
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart, optional: true

  def total_price 
    product.price.to_i * quantity.to_i
  end 
  
end
```

**order model**

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
    enum pay_type: {
        "Check" => 0, "Credit card" => 1, "Purchase order" => 2
    }
    validates :name, :address, :email, presence: true
    validates :pay_type, inclusion: pay_types.keys
  
    def add_line_items_from_cart(cart)
      cart.line_items.each do |item|
        item.cart_id = nil
        line_items << item
      end
    end
  
end
```

**product model**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :line_items 
    before_destroy :ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item

    private 

    def ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
        unless line_items.empty?
            errors.add(:base, 'Line Items present')
            throw :abort
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tackle it. :)

Assuming a `User` is a seller, who has many `Product`, of which you want to show `Product` that have many `LineItem` that are associated to a `complete` `Order`:

`current_user.products.joins(line_items: [:order]).where(orders: { completed: true })`

This will require that your associations are correct.

What this is effectively doing:

```
orders = Order.where(completed: true)
line_items = LineItems.where(order: orders)
products = current_user.products.where(id: line_items.pluck(:product_id)
```

But because you can do that in one call to your database (make sure your indexes are correct), you should.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```rb
LineItem.joins(:orders).where('orders.complete' => true)
```

It will show you only `LineItem-s` which belong to some `Order` with `complete` field set to `true`, which, I believe, marks the `Order` as complete.

Then just show this result whenever you want to show it.

Comment: alternative syntax for this is `LineItem.joins(:orders).where(orders: { complete: true })`